# There is at least one number in 10 consecutive numbers that is co-prime to product of others

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

The statement is as following.

In 10 consecutive numbers there exists at least one number which is co-prime to the product of the remaining numbers.

My strategy is that to eliminate most amount of numbers and see if there are any left to pick or not. For example we can not pick  multiples of $2$ so we eliminate it.
Now let's start.

In 10 consecutive numbers there are

$5$ times multiple of $2$

$3$ or $4$ times multiple of $3$ (since i want to eliminate the most amount of numbers assume it has 4 times multiple of 3)

$2$ times multiple of $5$

$1$ times multiple of 7

and if there is a multiple of any prime $p\gt7$ then it has to appear one time.

And do not forget that they might coincide or not. Since i want to eliminate the most i assume they coincide the minimum amount.

If there are $4$ times multiple of $3$ then $2$ of them are even so we already counted them by counting the multiples of $2$ and we are left with multiple of $3$ appears $2$ times.

Since multiple of $5$ appears $2$ times one of them is even so we are left with multiple of $5$ appears one time

now overall we have

$5$ times multiple of $2$

$2$ times multiple of $3$

$1$ times multiple of $5$

So we cannot pick these 8 numbers.

Now for $7$ if it is multiple of $2,3$ or $5$ we can not pick it either so the amount of numbers that we can not pick is 9. So there still left one number. If it is not multiple of any of the primes above then we can choose this number to satisfy the statement.

What do you think?

Is this correct?

Is there more efficient way to solve this?

EDIT: Actually there may be $2$ times multiples of $7$ which i want to assume since i want to eliminate most. But then one of the multiple of $7$ is even and we are left 1 multiple of $7$ again which can be considired as above. Thanks for warning

Comment: Do note: you could theoretically have 2 multiples of 7, in the same way that you could have 4 multiples of 3. I don't think this invalidates your point,
 though, since at least one must be a multiple of 2.

Comment: That is right. Thanks for note. @SDhn2a

Comment: @SDhn2a's comment shows why your statement "If it is actually $7$ then we pick it and we are done" will not work. E.g., if the numbers are $7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16$. The key point that you showed is that there must be some number $n$ that is not divisible by $2,3,5,$ or $7$, while the rest are divisible by at least one of those. Furthermore, any prime dividing $n$ is $>10$ and so cannot divide any of the other numbers.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for warning. I deleted that part. @kccu

Answer (score 0):

This is a good approach.  As SDhn2a pointed out, you could have two multiples of $7$ in your block of $10$.  When you eliminate the overcounting because some multiples of $3$ are even and have already been excluded, I would express it differently by saying there are five numbers we can exclude because there are multiples of $2$, at most two more that we can exclude because they are multiples of $3$ and not $2$, at most one more that we can exclude because it is a multiple of $5$, and at most one more that we can exclude because it is a multiple of $7$, so there is at least one left.

You also have to handle the case starting with $1$ by hand because $1$ can also be excluded without being a multiple of $2,3,5,7$, so there might be ten numbers excluded.  You just have to say $7$ is your example here.

Comment: that is a good point that i missed. Thank you!

Comment: You can say there is at most 1 odd multiple of 7, at most 1 odd multiple of 5, and at most 2 odd multiples of 3. So from the 5 odd numbers, there is at least 1 that is not divisible by 3,5,or 7.